# Google Earth Engine layer download issues

Tags: gis, zip, geotiff, google-earth-engine

I am unable to download the piece of my google earth engine layer that I need from the explorer. When I try to select the piece I need with the rectangle tool and hit download, windows kicks back an error message saying

> "Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (Zipped) folder (file path to folder) is invalid.

I tried downloading multiple times upon changing the rectangle selected, using the viewport selection instead, opening the zip folder in linux and OSX. But nothing worked. How do I solve this?

Comment: Any picture or more details on what you're trying to do? I'm getting confused. Are you downloading from Code Editor? What do you mean by 'explorer'? Are you still trying to download or you have downloaded the layer, but cannot open it?

Comment: Kevin, I'm using the GUI they provide rather than the Code Editor, it's called Google Earth Engine Explorer (https://explorer.earthengine.google.com/#workspace) it has some really useful tools built in: I'm using its naive Bayes classifier to define a layer (vegetation, bedrock, salt, soft sand etc. in the Utah desert) from Landsat 7 data, and am having issues trying to download this layer. The GUI kicks out a zipfile but this zipfile seems to be corrupted.

Comment: Hi dingo_ahab, sorry I'm not familiar with GEE Explorer. Just wonder have you tried exporting layer in Code Editor (if you just want a few layers) or using Python API (for a lot of layers)?